# Group the httpsamples if it has a specific substring in it

Tags: xslt

I Have a .jtl file which is the output of a jmeter run.
while generating the report, i want to group all samples under one thread if they have a substring "PASS".

Currently am trying the below code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/testResults/*[not(@lb = preceding::*/@lb)]">
            <xsl:variable name="label" select="substring-before(@lb,'@')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

where

```
lb = PASS@US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_model

      lb = PASS@US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_year
```

OutPut should be like:

```
PASS
   ->US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_model
   ->US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_year
```

But it is repeating twice since PASS is repeated twice.

please suggest

```
<xsl:for-each select="/testResults/*[not(@lb = preceding::*/@lb)]">
            <xsl:variable name="label" select="substring-before(@lb,'@')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

OutPut should be like

```
PASS
   ->US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_model
   ->US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_year
```

Output Got is:

```
PASS
   ->US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_model
   ->US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_year
PASS
   ->US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_model
   ->US_Edit_make_year_VehicleName_year
```

Comment: Not a good starting point - see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html